# mex binding error in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2008, wshttpbinding

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .NET 3.0. I am using a self-hosted WCF service. When executing the following statement, there is the following "binding not found" error. I have posted my whole app.config file, any ideas what is wrong?

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWCFService));
```

Error message:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the
>   endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpBinding. Registered base
>   address schemes are [https].

Full app.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding"
            closeTimeout="00:00:10"
            openTimeout="00:00:20"
            receiveTimeout="00:00:30"
            sendTimeout="00:00:40"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
            transactionFlow="false"
            hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000"
            messageEncoding="Mtom"
            proxyAddress="http://foo/bar"
            textEncoding="utf-16"
            useDefaultWebProxy="false">
          <reliableSession ordered="false"
               inactivityTimeout="00:02:00"
               enabled="true" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Digest"
               proxyCredentialType="None"
               realm="someRealm" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MyWCFService"
                behaviorConfiguration="mexServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:9090/MyService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="IMyService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The base address for your service defines "HTTPS://" - but your mex address is "HTTP".

If you want your service to use https://, you'll need to use the **mexHttpsBinding** as well:

```xml
<services>
    <service name="MyWCFService" behaviorConfiguration="mexServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:9090/MyService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" 
                binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" 
                contract="IMyService" 
        />
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
                contract="IMetadataExchange" 
        />
    </service>
</services>
```

Marc

Comment: Is it possible to have IMetadataExchange for both http and https as separate endpoints? What should be address fro them?

Comment: My question was about http: and https, not about net.tcp protocol.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim: sorry - misread that. But the same applies: you should be able to define a second base address, for `http://` and use that for the http mex endpoint.

Comment: Also the user needs to change the service metadata tag to enable https: 

'<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />'

Comment: Wish I could give this answer more than one upvote.  Been banging my head against a wall for a day and a half trying to get my silverlight app to work properly.  This finally did the trick

Answer (score 14):

Can I go for the double score? :)

As you're using WS-Http you are binding to an HTTPS protocol, so you need to use the correct MEX binding;

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Comment: this is the solution for me, thanks for share you config bro

Answer (score 4):

I've asked a question in a comment  for [Marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1026156/52277)

> Is it possible to have IMetadataExchange for both http and https as
>   separate endpoints?

marc_s answered

> you should be able to define a second base address, for http:// and
>   use that for the http mex endpoint.

So solution is to declare multiple endpoints with the SAME address="mex" and **different** bindings like the following

```
<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />  
<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpsBinding" address="mex"/>
```

Recently I found that it's easier to have one configuration switch that can be used to enable MEX on test and disable on Live.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx

> It's possible to use the ServiceHostFactory class to create a custom 
>   derived from ServiceHost in the Internet Information Services
>   (IIS custom ServiceHost that adds the ServiceMetadataBehavior, (which
>   enables metadata publishing), even if this behavior is not explicitly
>   added in the service’s configuration file.
>
> Write the imperative code that enables metadata publishing once and
>   then reuse that code across several different services. This is
>   accomplished by creating a new class that derives from ServiceHost and
>   overrides the ApplyConfiguration() method to imperatively add the
>   metadata publishing behavior.

Example code from [Custom Service Host MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx)

```
//Add a metadata endpoint at each base address
//using the "/mex" addressing convention
foreach (Uri baseAddress in this.BaseAddresses)
{
    if (baseAddress.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
    {
        mexBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        this.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                                MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
                                "mex");
    }
    else if (baseAddress.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
    {
        mexBehavior.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
        this.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                                MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding(),
                                "mex");
    }
    else if (baseAddress.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeNetPipe)
    {
        this.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                                MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(),
                                "mex");
    }
    else if (baseAddress.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeNetTcp)
    {
        this.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                                MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
                                "mex");
    }
}
```